# Is it possible to obtain a drowned jockey?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I will soon be attempting to collect as many rare mobs as possible and was curious if it was even possible to obtain a drowned jockey since I know they dismount when submerged in water which also happens to be their condition for spawning. Can they maybe spawn on the surface and not dismount?

Is it possible to obtain one legitimately in survival?

Comment: I tried quite a few things and I can't see it being possible. For a drowned to spawn, it needs 2 blocks of water, which means any spawn situation will dismount the drowned. Getting a zombie to convert requires touching his head onto water, and doing that in any situation will dismount. I tried using half block, stairs, boats and minecarts and all of them were a failure.

Comment: If you want to post this as an answer I can close the question

Comment: Hard to disproove something with just a few examples. I don't quite see it as an answer, but if it sufices for you, sure!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"I tried quite a few things and I can't see it being possible. For a drowned to spawn, it needs 2 blocks of water, which means any spawn situation will dismount the drowned. Getting a zombie to convert requires touching his head onto water, and doing that in any situation will dismount. I tried using half block, stairs, boats and minecarts and all of them were a failure." –
BunnyMerz